# Duplicate a Multi-Site Subdomain

Tags: plugins, multisite, plugin-recommendation

just 1 click ..and it duplicates ALL content, settings, css, plugins..

im looking for a plugin that adds a new link to Sites admin;

Edit | Dashboard | Deactivate | Archive | Spam | Delete | Visit | **DUPLICATE**...

it should copy ALL settings/configs. 
and create a new subdomain instance in the **existing** Multisite

Comment: If you have ssh access a mysqldump and install of the same site can be automated that's even easier!

Comment: *This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form.*

Answer (score 2):

A quick edit option for |Delete|Visit|DUPLICATE seems a bit too tailor made.

Nonetheless, this plugin does exactly what you want with 2 clicks (on its own screen).
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-cloned-sites-for-wpmu-batch/

Answer (score 1):

if you want a plugin that can have a default setup when you create a new sub-site then give this a shot [WPMUDEV New Blog Template](http://premium.wpmudev.org/project/new-blog-template) do not let the name fool you it does what your somewhat looking for minus the Duplicate button but that would be no longer necessary.

Comment: When I started with Multisite, I tried many plugins from WPMUDEV. Was not exactly happy with their _update_ method, and then [this](http://goo.gl/622FW)... deleted all of them

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party here but wanted to mention for the benefit of future searchers that we had the same need and built a plugin for cloning/duplicating with all settings intact just like the OP describes.

It is called the [NS Cloner](http://wordpress.org/plugins/ns-cloner-site-copier), and it doesn't add a "Duplicate" action link as described here, but it makes the process almost that easy by creating an easy-to-use network admin page where you can select a source site and then create a perfect duplicate complete with all content, plugin settings, etc, and it tops the WPMUDev New Blog Template plugin by being free (their are some more advanced features you can add with add-ons but the very powerful core is forever free), adding more power/flexibility in cloning settings, and avoiding hangups with updates since it's a wordpress.org plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins that backup the database as well as WordPress files.

Looking at the [plugins associated with the backup tag](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/backup), the following look useful:

- BackupWordPress
- XCloner
- Backup and Move Plugin

Comment: ideally im looking for a plugin that adds a new link to Sites admin; Edit | Dashboard | Deactivate | Archive | Spam | Delete | Visit | **DUPLICATE**... it should copy ALL settings/configs. and create a new subdomain instance in my existing Multisite